# How to load new generated private API headers in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I'm dummy in iOS especially in private API.

I have application for testing and now I need to use private API (*this application not for App Store*).

I downloaded generated headers from [iOS-Runtime-Headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers) and what next?

Under `/System/Library/` I have list of libraries that contain `Frameworks`, ... ,`PrivateFrameworks` as well.

**Do I need to replace original framework with ones I copied from `iOS-Runtime-Headers`?**

Because I have other applications that use `Public API` only and I don't want to damage them.

From posted link they tell to validate library for example by:

```
NSBundle *b = [NSBundle 
        bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GAIA.framework"];
BOOL success = [b load];
```

But here the path points to original path.

Or I miss something,

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, don't replace any headers which are provided by Apple.

Generally, it's done one of two ways:

1) You can copy some of these headers to your project and just include these files the same way as you include any other headers

```
#import "SomeHeader.h"
```

2) Sometimes you have to sanitize them (edit them) a little bit. Quite often, these headers has something like in in them:

```
#import "NSObject.h"
```

And compliller won't be able to find it, because NSObject is built-in class. So, you need to remove this like.

3) If you just need couple of methods out of it, then Tuukka Nori solution is right.

On top of these, you will need to link (statically or dynamically) against appropriate private framework (just including headers isn't enough).

Comment: Generally I want to make device to go to sleep by Using Private API. I know that it doesn't refer to my question but I saw your answers in most questions refer to private API. Have you idea where to look proper header? Because most answers today not relevant (I use 6.1). Thank you anyways

Comment: @fessy: I wasn't able even to find a solution which works completely on ios 6.x. All these DimScreen and BlankScreen were only partially dimming screen (non of them completely turned off the screen). So, I am not sure. You can try to reverse engineer Springboard and search in there. However, it could be protected by some entitlement.

Answer (score 4):

Don't replace any files. Instead, write a header file with the symbol that you intend to use. If you need an Objective-C method, add a category with a unique name, e.g.

```
@interface NSString (MyOwnPrivateCategory)
- (void) privateMethodDeclaredInRuntimeHeaders;
@end
```

Import it and use the method as you like.

The sample code given shows how to load a framework at runtime in case you don't want to link to it. Since some frameworks are private, they might not be available in all versions of iOS.